# How a controller calls a function located inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have main controller I would like from the Main controller to call a function located inside a directive example :

```
angular.module('app',[]).
controller('mainCtrl',function($scope) {
      $scope.startProcess= function () {
                  //here how I like to call directive function like following :
                   directivename.doTheprocess();
              }

})
.directive('directivename',function (
      return {
              controller: function ($scope) {
                         $scope.doTheprocess= function () {
                                               $scope.fullname='Justfortest'
              template: <div class="popmod" ><input type=text ng-model="fullname" /></div>
             }

                         }
})
```

and HTML file is like:

Comment: inject the service...

Comment: You'd probably want to locate the directive function elsewhere and pass in  `$scope` when you call it.

Comment: there are a lot of ways to do this, but one for each purpose, please tell me what this `toTheProcess` function will do

Comment: @SergioFilhow in fact the directive is HTML element so it is opening this element as a popup  and fil the directive Input with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not creating a new scope for the directive it inherits the parent scope.  You can probably just call $scope.doTheProcess from inside your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you..

```
var app = angular.module('twitterApp', []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.loadMoreTweets = function () {
    alert("Loading tweets!");
  }
})

app.directive("enter", function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("mouseenter", function () {
      scope.loadMoreTweets();
    })
  }
})
```

or jst visit this link to get a good idea 
https://thinkster.io/egghead/directives-talking-to-controllers/

or visit this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/GeAAB/